# Google Ecommerce tracking code on site were is not thank you page

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce, tracking

I would like to implement GA ecommerce code on my shop, but I have one problem - there is no "thank you page".

It works like client click on the button "confirm" and then appears jquery alert "thank you for buy" without reloading page etc. that`s all

Is some possibilities to implement ecommerce with full functionalists in such case?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to bind an event listener to the button "confirm" with function which will send all ecommerce data to GA. Something like this:

```
$("button[name=confirm]").on("click", function(){

  _gaq.push(['_addTrans',
   ...
  ]);

  _gaq.push(['_addItem',
   ...
  ]);

  _gaq.push(['_trackTrans']);

});
```

Comment: This would register a transaction even if the actual transaction has failed - presumably there is some kind of ajax action going on that actually sends the transaction to the server. In that case it might be better to hook into that via a global ajax handler - http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/ would be the way to go.